# Почему после приведения строк к Object они не равны?

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Я понимаю что такое интернирование строк, но результат выполнения данного кода мне непонятен.
Почему в 3 случае у нас false, а в 4 true?

```
string s1 = String.Format("{0}{1}", "abc", "cba");
string s2 = "abc" + "cba";
string s3 = "abccba";

Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2); // true
Console.WriteLine(s2 == s3); // true
Console.WriteLine((object)s1 == (object)s2); // false
Console.WriteLine((object)s2 == (object)s3); // true
```

Интересует именно отличие между двумя казалось бы аналогичными случаями.

Comment: В самом последнем варианте `true` потому что "сумма" строк будет вычислена на этапе компиляции и, благодаря интернированию, обе переменных получат ссылку на один и тот же объект: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4FcoEsB2BzABAZQE9Y4wBuAWACgAHFYAG3QGNdmHopcBhXAb2q4huOoxa4AbgHt0AE1wBZABQBKfoOGbYCLHigBGXAF4CMHTgB0AMSkJIMJQCI+ABgC+ffW8cAaXI4hgZl9/ZmAIRxVKKgBIGO1dXCgAJmN/QODcAGpQ8MdouIScJIBmNICgsIjozU0NWp4pTCgpBjgLAHUdeAAZLDglA2MTFKjcAHpx3DMUOGo47iaWts7uuD7MAZTh0rHJ6YRZ+ZjF5tb2rvRe/qUlKWAAKzhmGBUhoxM7x+fX0bIJqYAMwgDCgc1iJyW51WV3WNy+Txeb1SH1wCJ+bxKeymM3Bmjc1DcQA==

Comment: Но ведь s1 то равно s2, как и s2 == s3, в чем же отличие после приведения типа к object?

Comment: Потому что операция `==` переопределена для строк и она смотрит на то, что лежит в этих строках, а не просто на адрес в ОЗУ, как это делается для `object`

Comment: @Anamnian, так переоткрыть или нет?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не сразу заметил ссылки на вопрос про interning, не могу сейчас сказать нужно ли переоткрывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс String переопределяет метод Object.Equals, в результате чего сравнение происходит не по ссылке, а по значению.

> Для предопределенных типов значений оператор равенства (==) возвращает
>   значение true, если значения его операндов равны, и false в любых
>   остальных случаях. Для ссылочных типов (кроме string) оператор ==
>   возвращает true, если оба его операнда ссылаются на один и тот же
>   объект. Для типа string оператор == сравнивает значения строк.

При использовании строк в C#, CLR делает что-то хитрое и это что-то называется интернирование строк. Это способ хранения одной копии любой строки. Если вы храните в ста или, что еще хуже, в миллионе строковых переменных одинаковое значение получится, что память для хранения значений строк будет выделяться снова и снова. Интернирование строки это способ обойти эту проблему. Среда CLR поддерживает таблицу называемую пул интернирования. Эта таблица содержит одну уникальную ссылку на каждую строку, которая либо объявлена, либо создана программно во время выполнения вашей программы.

При помощи оператора + для конкатенации получаем поведение, как если бы вы использовали литерал «abccba», но String.Format() выполняется во время выполнения, а это значит что мы получаем совсем другие инструкции языка IL:

Код:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("abc" + "cba");
            Console.WriteLine("abccba");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}", "abc", "cba"));
        }
    }
}
```

Инструкции языка IL:

[image: Инструкции языка IL]

Как видите, мы получили две одинаковые строки для первой и второй команды, и отличную от них строку для 3 команды. Соответственно в пуле интернирования они будут представляться разными строками.

---

**UPD:** Я пошел чуть дальше и добавил еще одну строку:

```
string s1 = String.Format("{0}{1}", "abc", "cba");
string s2 = "abc" + "cba";
string s3 = "abccba";
string s4 = String.Format("{0}", "abccba");

Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2); // true
Console.WriteLine(s2 == s3); // true
Console.WriteLine(s1 == s4); // true

Console.WriteLine((object)s1 == (object)s2); // false
Console.WriteLine((object)s2 == (object)s3); // true 
Console.WriteLine((object)s1 == (object)s4); // false
```

[image: Инструкции языка IL]

Как видите, в приведенном выше листинге строки `s1` и `s4` представляют собой разные объекты во время выполнения программы.